# Unknown fragment after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation

In my application I create a fragment with the keyword `new` and set it by `FragmentTransaction`.

Upon rotation a stumbled upon a `NullPointerException` in the method `onActivityCreated()` indicating a missing injection, that I do after the call to `new`. I suspected the fragment was not created by my code und proved this by logging the `hashCode()`. It looks like a fragment is created automatically by the system upon rotation.

- Where does it come from?
- Is it created by the fragment manager?
- How am I supposed to use it correctly?
- How can I access it, to set the missing value?

For now I ignore it by testing for the null value, in which case `onActivityCreated()` does nothing. Instead use the fragment I create with `new`. However, this does not feel very satisfying, to throw away an object, that was already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where does it come from? Is it created by the fragment manager?**

On Activity recreation, Android will restore the fragments which already exist in activity's fragments manager

**How am I supposed to use it correctly?**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 if(savedInstanceState == null){
   //activity is created for first time
   //commit the fragment
 }else{
   //Activity is recreated(by means of rotation or something else)
   //Dont commit the fragment, fragmet will be restored by the system
 }
}
```

**How can I access it, to set the missing value?**

Normally, you have to handle this inside the fragment using `onSaveInstanceState` method. You can get the fragment instance by using, `getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container)` or `getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tagName)`

Comment: Thank you very much. That the fragments manager restores all fragments, makes the developer guide more clear. -- Then it obviously finds it's appropriate place without explicitly committing. I assume this auto commit finds it's place by the old id. The docs don't explain this and at what point of the lifecycle this auto commit happens. -- Guess the auto commit will not work for containers added after this point in the lifecycle.